# Inner product orthogonal projections

Tags: linear-algebra

$$
\langle f,g\rangle = \int^1_0f(x)g(x)dx
$$
in the vector space $C^0[0,1]$ of continuous functions on the domain $[0,1]$ to find the orthogonal projection of $f(x)=4x2+5$ onto the subspace $V$ spanned by $g(x)=x$ and $h(x)=1$. (Caution: $x$ and $1$ do not form an orthogonal basis of $V$.)

Attempt at a solution: So I took the $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ and formed the matrix
<1,1> 
<1,x>

But I'm confused as to where to go when I get here...

Comment: Try using Gram-Smith process to find an ortogonal basis.

Comment: *(Gram-Schmidt)*

Answer (score 1):

The orthogonal projection of $4x^{2}+5$ onto the subspace spanned by $1$ and $x$ is the unique $p(x) = \alpha x+\beta$ for which $(4x^{2}+5-p)\perp x$ and $(4x^{2}+5-p)\perp 1$. This gives you two equations in the two unknowns $\alpha,\beta$.
$$
           \int_{0}^{1}(4x^{2}+5-\alpha x-\beta 1)x\,dx =0,\\
           \int_{0}^{1}(4x^{2}+5-\alpha x-\beta 1)1\,dx = 0.
$$
The equations are
$$
          6-\frac{1}{3}\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\beta = 0,\\
          \frac{19}{3}-\frac{1}{2}\alpha-\beta = 0.
$$
Solve for $\alpha$, $\beta$ and you have the projection $p(x)=\alpha x+\beta$.